# android alert dialog not showing

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an alert inside of an onTouchListener but I can't get it to show. I am pretty new at this but I have been following some good tutorials to no avail.
This is part of the code...any ideas why this alert won't show?

```
mSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
   {
   }

   @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   {
      // the attempt at the alert
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                   {
                      MyActivity.this.finish();
                   }
                })
             .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                   {
                      dialog.cancel();
                   }
                });
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      return false;
   }
});
```

I think my structure is ok, but I can't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the code so the brackets are in the proper place.  It should compile now.  And as JLund points out, change the last line from `builder.create();` to `builder.show();` and that should work.  If you wish to keep the `builder.create();` call, just add `alert.show();` after it.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

to

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
```

Comment: But there's no reason to declare the alert variable as it's not being used within the block.

Comment: just use a "builder.show();" and you have no troubles!

Answer (score 0):

You almost done to display your dialog alert, but it seems that you forgot to display your *AlertDialog*,use `show()` of `AlertDialog`.
add this line to end of your code,but before `return false;` inside `onTouch()`.
`alert.show();`